# Integration between Cookiebot and SalesForceMarketingCloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, landing-page, cookies, custom-index

In my client we try to connect Marketing Cloud with Cookiebot. Cookiebot is a site that collects and stores cookies for each landing page. For this to be possible, we must create an index of all our LPs. The address of this index must be exactly the same as the domain address. ([www.mydomain.es](http://www.mydomain.es))
On the other hand, when I create a new LP in Marketing cloud I find a menu where it tells me to complete the URL as follows:
[www.mydomain.es/completeURL](http://www.mydomain.es/completeURL)
Forcing me to complete the URL and this is my main problem. And is that for cookiebot to read the Marketing cloud LP the page [www.mydomain.es](http://www.mydomain.es) must contain all the LP that I want cookiebot to read, otherwise it would not be collecting all the cookies properly.

Could someone help me to configure the index within the domain URL for Cookiebot to read it correctly?

Thank you all very much,

Almudena

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to create a Cloud Page on the root address.
Given that you have a SAP/Private Domain:

- marketing.example.com

you will be forced to, as you also write yourself, to create landing pages with unique addresses, e.g.

- marketing.example.com/page 1
- marketing.example.com/page2

marketing.example.com will remain inactive, returning an error code. This is a limitation of the Private Domain/Cloud Pages feature of Marketing Cloud.